# sql Server error - 3709

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, asp-classic, ado

Hi I keep getting the error:

Error (3709) - /mysite/Pages_Secure/mypage.asp ADODB.Recordset.

"The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.."

```
strQuery = ""
strQuery = strQuery + "SET ROWCOUNT 0 "
strQuery = strQuery + "SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, USER_TEAM_ID, USER_SERVICE_ID, USER_DIRECTORATE_ID "
strQuery = strQuery + "FROM Web_Users "
strQuery = strQuery + "WHERE USER_ID = '" + Cstr(lOwnerID) + "'"

CALL subOpenConnection("", "")

Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

RS.Open strQuery, objDBConnection
```

Error happens here after the open....

```
SUB subOpenConnection( strErrorPage, strErrorQueryArguments )

    Set objDBConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    objDBConnection.ConnectionTimeout = Application("ConnectionTimeout")
    objDBConnection.CommandTimeout = Application("CommandTimeout")
    objDBConnection.CursorLocation = Application("CursorLocation")
    objDBConnection.Open Application("ConnectionString") 

END SUB
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're using SUB rather than FUNCTION. The sub won't return the connection object (which is why you get an error that it's closed), whereas a function can return the connection object. Does this sub work anywhere else? Or is this the only time it's used?

Comment: The only other thing i could think of is removing the set rowcount from the SQL string because i would normally be running something like that within a stored proc. I've always thought that ADO wouldn't be able to do anything more than 1 statement per recordset.

Answer (score 0):

ok managed to get this working...can't quite remember how - but was something i had missed! D'oh!